# How can I select available seats while booking a bus online (www.redbus.in) using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

Visit below link for the steps:-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1dzl74txcev0r0/Steps.png?dl=0

The seats are shown in a canvas

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You can not locate an element in canvas, It is canvas element I don't think you can locate it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Sikuli** for GUI Automation

**Sikuli** automates anything you see on screen using the image recognition method to identify GUI elements. Sikuli script allows users to automate GUI interaction by using screenshots.

You can get more info from below links-
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/sikuli-tutorial-part-1/
http://www.devengineering.com/blog/testing/how-integrate-sikuli-script-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

You can not locate an element in canvas, It is canvas element I don't think you can locate it.

it is canvas like this

```
 <canvas class="pointer" data-type="lower" width="454" height="211"/>
```

and seats are embed to it

Answer (score -2):

```
 try
     {
     if(seats.size()>0)
     {
         for(WebElement abc : seats)
         {
             if(abc.isEnabled())
             {
                 abc.click();
                 totalEnabledElements++;
             }
         }
     }
     }
```

Comment: what is `seats`?